# Does MySqlDump have a problem backing up big database?

Tags: mysql

Is there any limitations on the size of a MySQL database that can be backed up with MySql Dump

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only limitation as I see it is the actual filesize that the filesystem supports.

I have successfully backed up several GB of data using mysqldump. Or are you talking several hundreds of GB or even TB?

Keep in mind that the dump-file generated by mysqldump might be bigger than your actual data depending on how much indexes you have.

Comment: I would say, no problem at all, unless you're backing up into a FAT32 partition :)